# Connecting UWP App to Remote SQL Server 2008 provider: TCP Provider, error: 0

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, tcp, uwp, database-connection

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The operation completed successfully)'

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 database with a UWP APP.

- Remote Access is enabled
- Firewall rules are in place
- Target version is Windows 10 Fall Creators Update(10.0; Bulid 16299
- Min version is Windows 10 Fall Creators Update(10.0; Bulid 16299
- Package.appxmanifest is setup with

  - internetClient
  - internetClientServer
  - privateNetworkClientServer
  - enterpriseAuthentication

Code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

const string ConnectionString = "SERVER = XXXServer; DATABASE =     XXXDatabase; USER ID = XXXUser; PASSWORD = XXXPass";

using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();

        }
```

Comment: Did this problem solved by you? I am also having this same error, I want to know how you resolved this error?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the connection between UWP app and SQL server 2008 R2, and can reproduce your issue. I also tested the connection between UWP app and SQL server 2017, with the same code snippet, same configuration for SQL server, it worked very well. So that as a workaround I strongly recommend you to upgrade the SQL server to 2017 since SQL server 2008 R2 is already out of date that [not supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/lifecycle/search?alpha=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%202008%20Developer).

Additionally, don't forgget to [Enable TCP/IP Network Protocol for SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672(v=sql.110).aspx)
 which you didn't mention it in above description.